# Nodejs Posgresql how to watch for a new database record insert

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql

Is it possible to somehow watch my Postgresql database from my Nodejs Express service and kick off a function when a new record was inserted into the database?

NOT: receiving the insert call and running a function. The function should kick off even if someone inserts a record through something like pgAdmin.

NOT: adding a trigger in the database. I need to send emails and so on, so preferably I would like a solution from within my Nodejs Express service, but I will still listen to database trigger ideas.

Comment: Take a look at this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-events

Comment: @Yidna You are referring to a `mysql` tool, I need help on `postgres`

Comment: Make a trigger that makes an HTTP (or even socket) call (connection) to node server?

Answer (score 3):

This is a moderately complicated question. Ideally, you have an API for end users to change the state of your system, and you can intercept the events in that API, rather than having a solution at the database-layer. This provides you with the best abstraction, and fewest side effects - "send an email" is a side effect of "insert into orders values(???)".

However, your question is clear - you want to track the inserts.

You have two options: pull versus push.

The pull version means you run a [scheduled job](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) which runs at whatever frequency your application demands, and finds changes you're interested in. This will probably require a log table in your database, allowing you to track changed data. For instance, if you're tracking "orders", you might have a table called "processed_orders", with `order_id, status, processed_date`, and you run a query along the lines of `select * from orders where order_id not in (select order_id from processed_orders`, and then do whatever you need to do; once that's complete, put a row into processed_orders.

This has a couple of benefits: it's testable, the "side effect" of sending an email can be switched off which is handy when you're doing bulk inserts (e.g. after restoring a backup), you have an audit trail, and you can control the performance impact. The drawbacks are the delay between the database operation and the email sending. You may notice a performance impact if you have lots of scheduled jobs doing similar tasks.

The "push" option I'm aware of is using database triggers. You can write a custom [trigger in JavaScript](https://plv8.github.io/) if you really want, though I'd recommend against doing the email sending in the context of the trigger - the performance impact would likely be horrible.

You could use an [event streaming](https://github.com/tmc/pqstream) framework, which notifies you of changes based on your configuration settings. Google is your friend.

Finally, you can use the [pg_notify](https://medium.com/@simon.white/postgres-publish-subscribe-with-nodejs-996a7e45f88) feature in Postgres, which uses fairly minimal trigger logic to notify listening applications of changes.

These options have the benefit of being (almost) instantaneous in notifying the application of database changes, and event streams neatly disconnect the "listener" from the database. However, you'd have to pay careful attention to the performance aspects, and you may need to be able to switch off the email sending e.g. when doing bulk data operations.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL provides the `NOTIFY` [1] and `LISTEN` [2] commands to achieve that.
Overall, the idea is to have your NodeJS service *listening* for *notifications* from PostgreSQL.

Found this for you: https://github.com/andywer/pg-listen - it might give you an idea on how to do it in practice.

[1] https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html

[2] https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-listen.html